# Função não retorna valores

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sou iniciante no JS e to tendo alguns problemas com a função abaixo.
Não estou conseguindo retornar o array com este código. Ele é apenas retornado quando eu removo o "vet = []" onde esvazio o mesmo (algo necessário).

A função deve gerar e retornar um vetor gerado aleatoriamente com tamanho definido a partir de uma seleção feita na página onde o usuário escolhe 10, 100, 1000, 10000 ou 100000 elementos para o vetor.

```
function Valeatorio(vet){
    let tamanho = document.getElementById("TVetor").value
    vet = [] //Removendo esse trecho o Array retorna
    if (tamanho > 0 && tamanho <= 10){
        console.time("Vetor Aleatório")
        for (let i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
                vet.push(parseInt(Math.random() * 100))
            } 
        console.timeEnd("Vetor Aleatório")
        console.log(vet)
        document.getElementById('VetorG').innerHTML = `<strong>Vetor gerado:</strong><br>${vet}`
    } else if(tamanho > 10){
        console.time("Vetor Aleatório")
        for (let i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
                vet.push(parseInt(Math.random() * 100))
            }
        console.timeEnd("Vetor Aleatório")
        console.log(vet)
        document.getElementById('VetorG').innerHTML = "<strong>Vetor gerado:</strong><br>Tamanho máximo permitido para visualização ultrapassado" 
    } 
    return [vet]
}
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Ola @Galbert22, Bem vindo ao SOpt, antes de começar de uma olhada em nosso [Tour]. Sobre sua pergunta se sua intenção é retornar um `Array` com esses valores, me parece que esta faltando  abrir e fechar *conchete*, ficando +/- assim `return [ tamanho, vet1, vet2, vet3 ];`, por esse motivo estou sinalizando como **erro de digitação** =D

Comment: Além disso, o trecho `vet1 = [], vet2 = [], vet3 = []` está sobre-escrevendo os parâmetros `vet1`, `vet2` e `vet3`. Isso é realmente o que você quer fazer? E ainda mais: `Valeatório` não é um nome de função válido no JavaScript, já que inclui um acento (`ó`).

Comment: Eu acabei modificando o código nesse meio tempo, vou editar a postagem principal deixando-o como está.
Utilizando os colchetes para retornar o valor não adiantou e, sim, sobreescrever os parâmetros sempre que a função for chamada é o que eu gostaria de fazer.

Comment: Você poderia editar a sua pergunta novamente para adicionar o trecho do código HTML que é necessário para o funcionamento do código? Se possível, adicione um _snippet_ executável.

Comment: Suas condições não abrangem todas as possibilidades, se `tamanho` for negativo a função não retorna nada, e aparentemente você espera que sua função sempre retorne algo. Outra coisa, pra que você recebe o argumento `vet` se vai sempre sobrescrevê-lo a cada chamada de função? Você poderia simplesmente criar um vetor vazio quando precisar e pronto.

Comment: Por que você retorna [vet], e não vet?

Comment: Você também deve atentar que `input.value` retorna uma string, então você deveria fazer a conversão para inteiro antes de usá-la para comparações. Você pode usar o método `parseInt(input.value, 10)` (eu sempre uso o 2º parâmetro, _radix_, para garantir que o navegador não interpreta strings numéricas começadas em zero como octal)

Comment: Além disso... Qual a necessidade do `parseInt` no `Math.random()`, que já retorna um inteiro? (Em: `parseInt(Math.random() * 100)`)

Comment: Luiz, [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) retorna um float.

Comment: E seria melhor usar a função [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) com o random, a operação matemática é mais eficiente do que todo o processo de parsing de string. Ex.: `Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);`

Comment: Enfim Galbert22, tem bastante coisa que dá pra melhorar na sua função, só que não dá pra simplesmente mudar seu código para o que eu acho que é melhor. Seria legal se você explicasse o que essa função deveria fazer e para quê o resultado dela será usado. Dessa maneira poderíamos te ajudar com muita mais rapidez e eficácia.

Comment: Editei novamente o post original com as informações sobre a utilidade dessa fução, obrigado @fernandosavio pela dica.

Comment: Como eu disse no post, se eu não limpar o vetor quando a função for chamada, ela retorna sem nenhum problema. Mas a limpeza é necessária para não acumular os números sempre que ele for gerar os aleatórios.

Answer (score 2):

Vou tentar recriar essa função baseado no que você disse em:

> A função deve gerar e retornar um vetor gerado aleatoriamente com tamanho definido a partir de uma seleção feita na página onde o usuário escolhe 10, 100, 1000, 10000 ou 100000 elementos para o vetor.

E também vou supor que arrays com mais de 10 elementos não devem ser mostrados para o usuário por questões de apresentação pelo que vi do seu código.

Então vou quebrar o problema em partes:

1. Criar uma função que gere um array de N números aleatórios
2. Receber o tamanho do array de um input do usuário
3. Apresentar (ou não) o novo vetor para o usuário

Vou tentar deixar bem explicado para que você entenda os motivos das minhas decisões:

> **1.  uma função que gere um array de N números aleatórios**

A função abaixo gera um array do tamanho definido pelo argumento `tamanho` preenchido com valores aleatórios entre 0 e 99.

```
function gera_array(tamanho) {
    // Cria o novo array
    let novo_array = [];

    // Popula o array
    for (let i=0 ; i < tamanho ; i++) {
        novo_array.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100))
    }

    // Retorna o novo array populado
    return novo_array;
}
```

> **2. Receber o tamanho do array de um input do usuário**

Para receber o valor de um `<input>` do usuário vou apenas converter o atributo `input.value` para um inteiro e usá-lo como parâmetro para a função `gera_array`.

```
// Guarda a referência para o elemento HTML
let input_tamanho = document.querySelector("#tamanho")
// Converte `input.value` para inteiro
let tamanho = parseInt(input_tamanho.value, 10)
```

Repare que criei uma variável `input_tamanho` guardando a referência ao elemento HTML. Fiz isso porque pesquisar na árvore DOM é computacionalmente caro para o navegador, mas como eu salvei sua referência basta usar `input_tamanho` sempre que eu precisar sem que o navegador tenha que procurar pelo elemento no DOM novamente.

*Obs.: A dica de salvar a referência para o elemento HTML não é obrigatória, mas todo mundo deveria fazer isso e entender o porquê.*

> **3. Apresentar (ou não) o novo vetor para o usuário**

Vou criar uma função que lê o array e retorna uma string para ser colocada no HTML como *feedback* para o usuário.

```
function array_to_string(array) {
    if (array.length <= 10) {
        return "[" + array.join(", ") + "]"
    else {
        return "Array muito grande para visualizar"
    }
```

---

Agora juntando tudo teríamos:

```js
function gera_array(tamanho) {
    let novo_array = [];

    for (let i=0 ; i < tamanho ; i++) {
        novo_array.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100))
    }
    return novo_array;
}

function array_to_string(array) {
    if (array.length <= 10) {
        return "[" + array.join(", ") + "]"
    } else {
        return "Array muito grande para visualizar"
    }
}

// referências:
let input_tamanho = document.querySelector("#tamanho")
let btn = document.querySelector("#btn")
let resultado = document.querySelector("#resultado")

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let tamanho = parseInt(input_tamanho.value, 10)
    let vetor = gera_array(tamanho)
    
    resultado.innerHTML = array_to_string(vetor)
})
```

```html
<input id="tamanho" type="number" value="10">
<button id="btn">Criar array</button>

<p id="resultado">Resultado...</p>
```

Comment: Aprendi algumas coisas com seu post, muito obrigado. ♥
Mas continuo sem compreender o porquê da minha função não retornar o array.

Comment: Outra hora edito e melhoro a resposta. :D

Comment: @Galbert22 Sua função retorna normalmente. [Veja](https://jsfiddle.net/f8xmb05z/1/)